# How do you use a list of dataframe names to perform data cleansing operations?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of DataFrame names stored in a list like this:

```
target_dfs = []
for x in np.arange(1950, 2020) :
    target_dfs.append('df_stat_data_' + str(x))
```

This yields a list of strings. But the actual DataFrames with those names do exist.

How do I effectively use each value on the list as a DataFrame and do operations such as dropping the last 3 rows?

I am trying to avoid doing something like this:

```
df_stats_data_1950 = df_stats_data_1950.iloc[:-3]
...
df_stats_data_2020 = df_stats_data_2020.iloc[:-3]
```

Comment: Why dont you create a list of dataframes instead of a list of strings containing the names of the dataframes?

Comment: @BjörnB Because if I have to type each name of the dataframes, then I might as well do the data cleansing operations individually rather than iterating through a generated list. The shape and structure of the datframes are all the same and follow a naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a dictionary:

```py
target_dfs = {1950: df1, 1951: df2}
```

You can now do stuff like:

```
for x in np.arange(1950, 2020):
    target_dfs[x].iloc[:-3]
```